# Setting up cube map texture parameters in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++, windows

I see alot of tutorials and sources use the following code snippet when defining each face of a cube map:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, InternalFormat, size, size, 0, Format, Type, NULL);
```

Is it safe to assume `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X  + i` will properly iterate the following cube map targets, `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe because if you look at [the original extension spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_cube_map.txt) for cubemaps, you can see that those enums are all defined as consecutive numbers.

> ```
> Accepted by the <target> parameter of GetTexImage,
> GetTexLevelParameteriv, GetTexLevelParameterfv, TexImage2D,
> CopyTexImage2D, TexSubImage2D, and CopySubTexImage2D:
>
>     TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X_ARB     0x8515
>     TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X_ARB     0x8516
>     TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y_ARB     0x8517
>     TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y_ARB     0x8518
>     TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z_ARB     0x8519
>     TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z_ARB     0x851A
> ```